# How do I create Internal Load Balancer (ILB) using Azure Management SDK?

Tags: azure, internal-load-balancer

I want to configure an ILB for my Azure Cloud Service, similar to discussed in this article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-internal-getstarted/
- but using the .Net SDK instead of powershell. (Also I have some conceptual confusion about the article/powershell maybe people will be able to explain. For VM scenario you have to explicitly create the ILB, but it seems like for cloud service you do not - is it already created, or automatically created? Why are New-AzureVM commandlets being used in a cloud service context?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation has been updated
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-get-started-ilb-classic-cloud/

Or are you looking for a C# sample?

Comment: Nope, I didn't really need C#, a service definition doc is really what I wanted. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not be using cloud services. These are being deprecated. Just use v2 - Azure Resource Manager (portal.azure.com) and create a load balancer instead of a cloud service. Regardless, in v1 (Azure Service Management), when you create a VM, you automatically get a cloud service if you don't have one already - which is why new-azurevm is being used in cloud service context.

Comment: Hm. Is there any alternative PaaS thing coming to replace that, or should cloud services migrate to IaaS?

Comment: I'm not making this the accepted answer because well... rearchitect based on v2 isn't a great solution for nearly anyone who's already built something PaaS. :)